# jquery scrollLeft() not working

Tags: jquery

jquery scrollLeft not working.
Why this code doesn't work?
Background must change if div will scroll left. 
*contentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontentcontent*

```js
$(function() {
  scrollLeft = $('.page').scrollLeft();
  if (scrollLeft > 12) {
    $('.main-header').addClass('notleft');
  } else {
    $('.main-header').addClass('left');
  }
});
```

```css
.page {
  width: 600px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.wrap {
  width: 1000px;
}

.notleft {
  background: red;
}

.left {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <div class="wrap">
    <header class="main-header">
      dnjdksvnkjsdvdjskv
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [`.scrollLeft()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/): "_Get the **current horizontal position** of the scroll bar for the first element in the set of matched elements or set the horizontal position of the scroll bar for every matched element._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two issues. Firstly, you need to execute it within the `scroll` event handler for the `.page` element. Running it on load means that nothing will change. Secondly, you need to make the `.notleft` CSS rule more specific so that it overrides the `.left` rule and changes the background. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.page').scroll(function() {
    scrollLeft = $('.page').scrollLeft();
    if (scrollLeft > 12) {
      $('.main-header').addClass('notleft');
    } else {
      $('.main-header').addClass('left');
    }
  }).scroll();
});
```

```css
.page {
  width: 600px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.wrap {
  width: 1000px;
}

.left {
  background: green;
}
.left.notleft {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <div class="wrap">
    <header class="main-header">
      dnjdksvnkjsdvdjskv
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```